IPSEC not started on pinging another host
I have configured IPSec on my linux client using strongswan, on both remote_addrs and local_addrs, I have used %any.
When I start the charon-systemd daemon and then use swanctl --load-all, the out says that connections loaded.
When I ping from Windows client, IPSec is established and working fine.
When I ping from my strongswan client, ping packets are received on Windows without isakmp exchange at all.
I did not see this on debian 11, but on debian 12,  with same configuration file. I see this problem.
Here is the config.
connections {
        host_to_me {
                remote_addrs=%any
                local_addrs=%any
                version=1
                proposals=3des-sha1-ecp384, aes256-sha384-modp8192, aes256-sha384-modp2048, 
                 aes192-sha256-modp2048s256, 3des-sha1-modp1024,des-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha256- 
                modp2048, aes256gcm16-sha256-modp2048,aes128gcm16-sha256-modp2048
                dpd_timeout=120s
                reauth_time=4h
                dpd_delay=30s
                children {
                        host_to_me {
                                start_action=start
                                esp_proposals=des-sha1,3des-sha1,aes128-sha256, aes256-sha256
                                rekey_time=8h
                                dpd_action=restart
                                mode = transport
                        }

                }
                local-0 {
                        auth = psk
                }
                remote-0 {
                        auth = psk
                }
        } }

I am unable to start isakmp with a ping from this (strongswan configured IP) to Windows. But from Windows, it is working fine.

start_action=start does not trigger on traffic and it only works if you configure a remote address (to what host should the IKE SA get initiated otherwise?). For traffic triggered initiation, use start_action=trap, which does work with remote_addrs=%any but only for transport mode.
